# Rspec block (3 levels) in <top (required)> error

Tags: ruby, rspec, travis-ci

I am getting the following error in travis ci when committing a project:

```
Failures:

  1) salt on unsupported distributions we fail
     Failure/Error: expect { subject }.to raise_error(/Unsupported platform: Unsupported/)
       expected Exception with message matching /Unsupported platform: Unsupported/ but nothing was raised
     # ./spec/classes/salt_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 6.5 seconds
47 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/classes/salt_spec.rb:8 # salt on unsupported distributions we fail
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby -S rspec spec/classes/salt_spec.rb --color failed
```

And here is the `salt_spec.rb`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'salt' do

  context 'on unsupported distributions' do
    let(:facts) {{ :osfamily => 'Unsupported' }}

    it 'we fail' do
      expect { subject }.to raise_error(/Unsupported platform: Unsupported/)
    end
  end

  ['Debian', 'RedHat', 'SUSE', ].each do |distro|
    context "on #{distro}" do
      let(:facts) {{
          :osfamily => distro,
        }}

      it { should contain_class('salt::master::install') }
      it { should contain_class('salt::master::config') }
      it { should contain_class('salt::master::service') }
      it { should contain_class('salt::minion::install') }
      it { should contain_class('salt::minion::config') }
      it { should contain_class('salt::minion::service') }

      ##
      ## salt-master config file
      ##
      describe 'config file with default params' do
        it { should contain_file('/etc/salt/master')}
      end

      ##
      ## salt-minion config file
      ##
      describe 'config file with default params' do
        it { should contain_file('/etc/salt/minion')}
      end

      ##
      ## salt-master service
      ##
      describe 'service with default params' do
        it { should contain_service('salt-master').with(
          'ensure'     => 'running',
          'enable'     => 'true',
          'hasstatus'  => 'true',
          'hasrestart' => 'true'
          )}
      end
      ##
      ## salt-minion service
      ##
      describe 'service with default params' do
        it { should contain_service('salt-minion').with(
          'ensure'     => 'running',
          'enable'     => 'true',
          'hasstatus'  => 'true',
          'hasrestart' => 'true'
          )}
      end

      ##
      ## salt::master::install
      ##
      it 'installs the salt-master package' do
        should contain_package('salt-master').with(
        'ensure'   => 'present',
        'name'     => 'salt-master'
        )
      end
      ##
      ## salt::minion::install
      ##
      it 'installs the salt-minion package' do
        should contain_package('salt-minion').with(
        'ensure'   => 'present',
        'name'     => 'salt-minion'
        )
      end
    end
  end
  ['Archlinux', ].each do |distro|
    context "on #{distro}" do
      let(:facts) {{
          :osfamily => distro,
        }}

      it { should contain_class('salt::master::install') }
      it { should contain_class('salt::master::config') }
      it { should contain_class('salt::master::service') }
      it { should contain_class('salt::minion::install') }
      it { should contain_class('salt::minion::config') }
      it { should contain_class('salt::minion::service') }

      ##
      ## salt-master config file
      ##
      describe 'config file with default params' do
        it { should contain_file('/etc/salt/master')}
      end

      ##
      ## salt-minion config file
      ##
      describe 'config file with default params' do
        it { should contain_file('/etc/salt/minion')}
      end

      ##
      ## salt-master service
      ##
      describe 'service with default params' do
        it { should contain_service('salt-master').with(
          'ensure'     => 'running',
          'enable'     => 'true',
          'hasstatus'  => 'true',
          'hasrestart' => 'true'
          )}
      end
      ##
      ## salt-minion service
      ##
      describe 'service with default params' do
        it { should contain_service('salt-minion').with(
          'ensure'     => 'running',
          'enable'     => 'true',
          'hasstatus'  => 'true',
          'hasrestart' => 'true'
          )}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If I understand the `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>` correctly then the indentation is wrong somewhere between line 5 and 11, however it appears right to me. Any and all help with this would be greatly appreciated as this is my first time dealing with rspec and I am trying to learn.

***EDIT***
I have fixed this myself. I changed my code from this:

```
  context 'on unsupported distributions' do
    let(:facts) {{ :osfamily => 'Unsupported' }}

    it 'we fail' do
      expect { subject }.to raise_error(/Unsupported platform: Unsupported/)
    end
  end
```

To this:

```
  context 'on unsupported distributions' do
    let(:facts) {{ :osfamily => 'Unsupported' }}

    it 'we fail' do
      should compile.and_raise_error(/Unsupported platform: Unsupported/)
    end
  end
```

And it appears to be passing now. I guess my question is this: Is this correct or am I incorrectly passing the test?

Comment: No idea why this got a down vote. The answer wasn't immediately obvious and I had to search through git issues to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by changing the following:

context 'on unsupported distributions' do
    let(:facts) {{ :osfamily => 'Unsupported' }}

```
it 'we fail' do
  expect { subject }.to raise_error(/Unsupported platform: Unsupported/)
end
```

To this:

context 'on unsupported distributions' do
    let(:facts) {{ :osfamily => 'Unsupported' }}

```
it 'we fail' do
  should compile.and_raise_error(/Unsupported platform: Unsupported/)
end
```